# How to accept max 3 digits in (999) from "(999) 999-999-9999" jquery.maskedinput?

Tags: maskedinput

I have used following.

```
$('#abc').mask("(999) 999-999-9999")
```

Which allow exact 3 digits at (999) but I want to allow 1, 2 or 3 digits length in place of (999).